# package name appeared infront of resource

Tags: android, android-studio, android-resources

I just noticed that Android Studio prepended the package name in front of all resources used in the java source files.

For example

```
R.integer.someInt
```

became

```
com.mypackage.name.R.integer.someInt
```

It didn't cause any errors it just makes it really hard to read. I don't noticed that I changed a setting or somethig...
Does anyone know what I did?

Comment: check your imports. you might have imported a different R that is not part of your package. it should look like "import com.mypackage.name.R"

Comment: That does change it :) but I'm still confused: when I don't import R like you said an remove the prefix manually, it compiles and runs without errors